# getIntent() deprecated, usar correctamente parseUri() y toUri()

Tags: android

En la documentación de la clase Intent se dice que su método [getIntent()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#getIntent(java.lang.String)) está en desuso y que en su lugar se recomienda usar `parseUri()`. A su vez, en la sección de `parseUri()` se dice que el URI (su parámetro) puede ser retornado desde `toUri()`.

Entonces, lo que he estado intentando es iniciar una segunda actividad. En la segunda actividad intento recuperar el intent con `parseUri()` pasándo como parámetro el String que obtuve de `toUri()` en la actividad (visto por consola), pero no consigo que funcione.

Alguien me puede mostrar la forma correcta de usar estos métodos. Quiero decir, por ejemplo, asignar el URI devuelto por `toUri()` a una constante pública estática que luego pueda ser accedida desde otra clase para recuperar el intent mediante `parseUri()`.

Si no se entendió la pregunta, por favor vean este [ejemplo](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html?hl=es-419#DisplayMessage).
Ctrl + F para encontrar *getIntent()* (solo aparece una vez). Eso es lo que quiero conseguir. Pero en vez de `getIntent()`, usar `parseUri()` y `toUri()`.

Comment: Prueba con esto: `String url = "http://www.example.com";
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
startActivity(i);` [Ver esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3004542/5587982) de SO en inglés.

Comment: Prueba con esto: `String url = "http://www.example.com";
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
startActivity(i);` [Ver esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3004542/5587982) de SO en inglés. O bien algo así: `Intent i = Intent.parseUri(uri, 0);` [puedes ver varios ejemplos aquí](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?class=android.content.Intent&method=parseUri)

Comment: Los ejemplos de programcreek.com ya los había visto. Y en el otro ejemplo lo que se está haciendo es establecer los datos del intent (setData()). Yo no quiero eso, lo que quiero es obtener el intent desde otra clase.

Comment: Si lo que quieres es recuperar el valor de la URI en `TuOtraActivity`, lo puedes hacer con: `getIntent().getStringExtra("URL")` suponiendo que creaste el `Intent` así: `Intent i = new Intent(this, TuOtraActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("URL", Uri.parse(url));
                startActivity(i);` Creo que deberías explicar mejor el contexto en tu pregunta para poder ayudarte mejor. En la pregunta no dices lo que quieres hacer en sí. El intent puede servir para varias cosas, y dependiendo de eso habrá que proceder de una manera o de otra.

Comment: El método getIntent() está en desuso. En la documentación se recomienda usar parseUri(). Mi pregunta es cómo usar correctamente este último en conjunto con toUri(). Cómo hacer lo que se lograría con getIntent().

Comment: Agregué un link en mi pregunta original.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El método para obtener los datos del `Intent` que inició una actividad no es otro que **el método `getIntent` de la clase `Activity`, el cual no es obsoleto**.

De la [documentación de Android](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getIntent()):

> ### `getIntent`
>
> ```
> Intent getIntent ()
> ```
>
> Return the intent that started this activity.

Como puedes ver, no hay ninguna noticia de que dicho método esté deprecated.

El método que ha sido declarado obsoleto es `getIntent` de la clase `Intent`, como bien indicas en tu pregunta.

Para más seguridad, [el ejemplo oficial](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html?hl=es-419#DisplayMessage) que Android muestra para obtener los datos del `Intent` que inició una actividad está basado en `getIntent()`:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message);
    
    // Get the Intent that started this activity and extract the string
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

    // Capture the layout's TextView and set the string as its text
    TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);
    textView.setText(message);
}
```

En ningún momento Android dice que, en este caso, haya que recurrir a `parseUri`. Además, `parseUri` no obtiene un `Intent` sino que **crea uno nuevo**, [tal y como dice la definición del método](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#parseUri(java.lang.String,%20int)):

> #### parseUri
>
> ```
> Intent parseUri (String uri, 
>                 int flags)
> ```
>
> **Create an intent from a URI.** This URI may encode the action, category, and other intent fields, if it was returned by toUri(int).
> If the Intent was not generate by toUri(), its data will be the entire
> URI and its action will be ACTION_VIEW.

Espero que con esto tu duda quede aclarada.

Comment: Muchas gracias! Había entendido las cosas mal. Tu respuesta es muy clara. Gracias.

Comment: @felipe Me alegro de que la respuesta te haya ayudado a resolver tu duda. Por favor, cuando sea posible l◔_◔: **[¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)** en el Centro de Ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que buscas es enviar a través de un Intent algunas variables(parámetros) te recomiendo usar:

```
Intent i= new Intent();
i.putExtra("nombreCampo", "contenido");
```

Y luego para obtenerlo:

```
String id = intent.getStringExtra("nombreCampo"); //Dentro estará "contenido"
```

Espero que te sea de ayuda.

Comment: Mi pregunta es como obtener el intent de la forma correcta, no como obtener los datos que contiene.

Comment: pero si estoy dentro de una clase Location: service(){.....

como puedo obetener la data "nombreCampo", entiendo intent que es para activitis